# Bypassing the different server PHP versions to install extensions

Tags: magento2, php, ssh, php-5.6, php-7.1

My SSH version is 5.4 but my server version is 7.1.
i used 
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs 
to bypass the errors and install Magento 2.3 but now i want to install extensions  using
bin/magento setup:upgrade.... the error  of SSH version of 5.4 is incompatible with it. i need to upgrade..

QUESTIONS are

1. is there any command i can add to 'bin/magento setup:upgrade' to bypass the errors
2. what commands do i used to upgrade php version 5.4 to 7.1.

Remember I am on a shared hosting platform

Answer (score 0):

I later got it and worked great for me

CHANGING SSH PHP VERSION TO 7.1

1. I found what I believe is a better solution. First, SSH into the server and run the following command: "whereis php". 
   This will give you a list of all PHP versions installed. Find the one you want (i.e. /opt/php56/bin/php).

Next, find and open the file in your home directory called ".bashrc". Add the following line to the end of the document (without quotes): "alias php=/opt/php56/bin/php" (change the PHP path if you want a different version)

php: /usr/bin/php 
/usr/local/bin/php 
/usr/local/lib/php.ini 
/opt/php53/bin/php 
/opt/php54/bin/php 
/opt/php71/bin/php 
/opt/php52/bin/php 
/opt/php55/bin/php 
/opt/phpedge/bin/php 
/opt/phpstable/bin/php 
/opt/php70/bin/php 
/opt/php56/bin/php

2.

place below both into .bashrc

## User specific aliases and functions

alias php=/opt/php71/bin/php
alias php='/opt/php71/bin/php'

and save

3. use below to load profile

source  ~/.bash_profile

4. use

php-v to check new version